# Executing promise after if statement like finally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
if( condition1 ) {
    return promise1(param).then(promiseFinal);
else if( condition2 ) {
    return promise2(param).then(promiseFinal);
else if( condition3 ) {
    return promise3(param).then(promiseFinal);
else...
```

Is there any way to run `promiseFinal` without having to specify it multiple times? What I tried didn't work:

```
return void function(param){
    if( condition1 ) {
        return promise1(param);
    } else if( condition2 ) {
        return promise2(param)
    }...
}().then(promiseFinal)
```

This code appears to result in branching, and network-related promises execute out of order. I'm certain there is a way to do this right, but I just can't think of anything right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `void` operator and that `param` parameter of the function expression that you are passing nothing into. Also you must not forget to always return a promise if no condition matched, as returning `undefined` will result in an exception.

```
return (function() {
    if (condition1)
        return promise1(param);
    else if (condition2)
        return promise2(param);
    else if (condition3)
        return promise3(param);
    else
        Promise.reject(new Error("nothing matched"))
}()).then(promiseFinal);
```

Using an IEFE is a quite fine approach for this. An alternative might be a ternary operator:

```
return (condition1
  ? promise1(param)
  : condition2
      ? promise2(param)
      : condition3
          ? promise3(param)
          : Promise.reject(new Error("nothing matched"))
).then(promiseFinal);
```

Comment: Does `void function(){}()` not do the same thing as `(function(){})()` ?

Comment: @sg.cc: No, the one returns `undefined` and ignores the return value of the function, that other does evaluate to the return value. The [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) does more than just being useful to turn a function in an expression - which here isn't even necessary, as you're inside of a `return` statement anyway. I included the parenthesis only for clarity, you can omit them if you want.

Comment: Thanks! I only now remember that `void` always returns `undefined`. That's what I get for trying to be clever.